Work done by a system of particles
I'm stuck trying to calculate the work done by a system of particles in a conservative field. Here is my attempt:
We have:
$$W_{01} = \sum_{a=1}^{N}\int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}}\vec{F}_{a} \cdot d\vec{r}_{a}
+ \sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N}\int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}} \vec{F_{ab}} \cdot d\vec{r}_a $$
where $\vec{r}_{0a} = \vec{r}_a(t=0)$ and $\vec{r}_{1a} = \vec{r}_a(t=t_1)$
The first integral is due to the external forces, there is no problem. My problem is with the second integral that is due to the interaction forces between particles:
$$\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N}\int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}} \vec{F_{ab}} \cdot d\vec{r}_a $$
I tried to separate the integral in two terms:
$$ \sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N}\int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}} \vec{F_{ab}} \cdot d\vec{r}_a  = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N} \int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}} \vec{F}_{ab}\cdot d\vec{r}_a+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N} \int_{\vec{r}_{0b}}^{\vec{r}_{1b}} \vec{F}_{ba} \cdot d\vec{r}_b $$
then I replace $\vec{F}_{ba} = -\vec{F}_{ab}$. This leads to:
$$ =\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N} \int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}}   \vec{F}_{ab}\cdot d\vec{r}_a - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N} \int_{\vec{r}_{0b}}^{\vec{r}_{1b}} \vec{F}_{ab} \cdot d\vec{r}_b $$
In this step I'm stuck. I searched in many books and the notation is not 100% clear for me. In Goldstein and he used a different notations in the integration limits. He used something like this in the integration limits:
$$ \int_{1}^{2} \nabla V_{ij} \cdot\vec{ds}_i $$
but this is quite confusing for me because I don't see the limits of integration explicitly.
The result should be
$$\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N}\int_{\vec{r}_{0a}}^{\vec{r}_{1a}} \vec{F}_{ab} \cdot d\vec{r}_a=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^{N} \sum_{b=1}^{N} \left[ V_{(a,b)}(|\vec{r}_{ab}^{\ (1)}|) - V_{(a,b)}(|\vec{r}_{ab}^{\ (0)}|)  \right]$$
with
$$\vec{r}_{ab}^{(1)} = \vec{r}_{1a} - \vec{r}_{1b}$$
$$\vec{r}_{ab}^{(0)} = \vec{r}_{0a} - \vec{r}_{0b}$$

Those results seem to assume curl free forces. Then you can use theorems to know the force can be expressed as a gradient of a scalar field. They are the boundary terms. You need to do partial integration. (Also called conservative forces.)

The sign of the scalar field is just a matter of convention for potentials. Just use the convention your book uses.

Voting to reopen. Obviousy a conceptual question and not a "do my homework for me" question.
